# Proper Ubercard search using Drupal 7 Views

Tags: filter, drupal-7, drupal-views

**Overview**
I wanted to create a product search in Drupal 7. I created a view and exposed the fields that I wanted to have exposed for searching (filtering). The search works perfect but only when you search for items using the Item Title.

**The Question:** 
I want a user to be able to type in a more "descriptive search" using all filters:

1. Title
2. Type
3. Variant
4. Size
5. SKU, etc

**View SQL Code Sample**

```
    SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.type AS node_type, node.language AS node_language, node.title AS node_title, uc_products.model AS uc_products_model, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_uc_product_image_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_product_variant_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_product_tags_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_body} field_data_body ON node.nid = field_data_body.entity_id AND (field_data_body.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_body.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_product_variant} field_data_field_product_variant ON node.nid = field_data_field_product_variant.entity_id AND (field_data_field_product_variant.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_product_variant.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {uc_products} uc_products ON node.vid = uc_products.vid
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('product')) AND (field_data_body.body_value LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (field_data_field_product_variant.field_product_variant_value LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '\\') ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC, node_title ASC
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0
```

I wish to find out what I am doing wrong. I wish to merge all the exposed filter entities into one so that they can be searched / filtered from the one search box.

You response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this module http://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate

But it only works with text filters (no combos etc.).